# Transparency in Eevee Blender 2.81 not working

Tags: rendering, node-editor, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I'm editing a tank and I followed transparency for glass tutorial using nodes. I would also like to ask why is my preview different with my rendered? I'm also new to blender so there's probably something wrong Im doing. I've also tried all the tutorial but still shows the same result.[image]

Comment: Could you post the .blend? It will be hard to tell the problem from the picture.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VgSVnHqiLzhGBsyaV0gOI8_quhTbIlfu Thank you so much T.T

Answer (score 2):

In EEVEE, I find that glass shaders don't work so well, so I leave them for cycles. For EEVEE, I use this arrangement to get realistic glass - pay attention to the blend modes I have highlighted on the right. If you absolutely must use a glass shader, go with the arrangement I placed above, but generally I find the one I have highlighted (framed) works best. I tinted it blue just to show it better with the fresnel. See image:

[image: EeveeGlass]

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try itt

Comment: This is the only trick that I found on the internet that worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using glass, it is usually better to use cycles to get a more realistic look. However, there is away to achieve a "cycles glass look" with EEVEE.

First, you can either use a principled shader and set the transmission to 1, or you can use a normal glass shader.

Then, check Screen Space Refraction in the settings dropdown.

[image]

In the render tab, check the Screen Space Reflections tab and check Refractions.

[image]

You can achieve a quite similar look to glass from cycles using this method.

Comment: I don't know why it's just turning gray :( I'm using 2.81 and it only have the checkbox for Screen Space Reflections :(

Comment: If you look at the question @caleb lee, the *preview* shows the material that the glass should be in Eevee, and it **is** clear.

Comment: And according to [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/QeAWv6P), if you want to be able to see *glass behind glass* you will need to enable in the Render Properties: Screen Space Reflections, Refraction, Half Res Trace. And in Material Options: Blend Mode → Additive, Transp. Shadow → Hashed, Show Backside → On, Screen Space Refraction → On, Subsurface Translucency → On. I haven't played with these settings yet myself, just spreading this little bit of knowledge I just discovered... because at first I thought it was impossible with Eevee.